# Is there a way to have my webpage automatically load a preselected page once a certain php function is complete

Tags: php, html, load

Essentially the title, please keep it simple, im not accustom with code.

Comment: So you want a method that runs something then redirects to a different page?

Comment: One of the "Do my homework/assignment for me kinda question."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `header('Location:yourpage.php')` at the end of your function.

[Header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)